# How to POST data on payload instead of formdata

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, alfresco, payload

I'm trying to make a request to an Alfresco service from a web-script I made, passing some json data on the payload.

This is the Alfresco service:

```
http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/internal/downloads
```

And I need to pass a json array whit some script node, like that:

```
var jsonData = "[{'nodeRef':'workspace://SpacesStore/920b43d4-e79c-40eb-96f3-1dff3a169929'},  {'nodeRef':'workspace://SpacesStore/f19fba4b-0cf6-4379-a858-70d0d7d9efb0'},{'nodeRef':'workspace://SpacesStore/6ea51288-9364-4070-a23b-499025a6c1f9'}]";
```

I make the call on this way

```
$.ajax({
    url: serviceUrl,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: jsonData
});
```

Unfortunately when I chek the request list from the developer tools I see that my json data are passed as Form data on the request and I get an internal server error response.

I saw the same service used on another website and there the data are passed as payload, so, I think really need the data to be passed on the payload.

Does anyone know how to force it ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think it depends on the Content-Type header of the request; if the content type is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" then it is shown under form data. If you put - for example - Content-Type: application/json the json should be part of the payload. You can use:

```
$.ajax({
    url: serviceUrl,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Comment: `contentType: "application/json"` does solve the issue!

Comment: + `JSON.stringify( jsonData )` could also solve some issues

Comment: The answer didn't resolve the issue for me, but `JSON.stringify(jsonData)` did.